# PyQt And MatPlotLib - (Embedded) Pie Chart without PyPlot

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, embed, pie-chart

I want to embed a pie chart of data produced by an analytics class method in my PyQt GUI. Using PyPlot or PyLab I have been able to plot the chart but only in a separate window.

```
class MyMplCanvas(FigureCanvas):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)

        self.compute_initial_figure()

        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, fig)
        self.setParent(parent)

        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self,
                                   QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding,
                                   QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)
```

Above is the canvas in which the pie chart should be displayed. I think I must use the self.axes parameter in embedding the chart but I don't know. Below is the code I have thus far for the pie chart:

```
class UsersPlatformPie(MyMplCanvas):

    def compute_initial_figure(self):

        UsersPerCountry, UsersPerPlatform = Analytics.UsersPerCountryOrPlatform()
        labels = []
        sizes = []
        print UsersPerPlatform
        for p, c in sorted(UsersPerPlatform.iteritems()):
            labels.append(p)
            sizes.append(c)
        colors = ['turquoise', 'yellowgreen', 'firebrick', 'lightsteelblue', 'royalblue']
        pylab.pie(sizes, colors = colors, labels = labels, autopct = '%1.1f%%', shadow = True)
        pylab.title('Users Per Platform')
        pylab.gca().set_aspect('1'); pylab.show()
```

I think this is superfluous but below is the establishment of the widget.

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        ...
        self.main_widget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        l = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.main_widget)
        UPP = UsersPlatformPie(self.main_widget, width=5, height=4, dpi=100)
        l.addWidget(UPP)
        self.main_widget.setFocus()
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.main_widget)
```

I am basing this code on [this](http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt4.html). I apologise for the code heavy nature of this question but I think at least the first two segments are necessary. Advice on either a new way of plotting the pie chart or connecting my pie chart to the canvas above will be much appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't appologize for showing too much code, but rather apologize for not showing a [mcve].

Comment: The reason I have not done this is that this is not an error as such. The middle segment does work, just not in the desired way.

Comment: It's not an error, but it's an undesired behaviour. Especially since you link to the question which shows the correct behaviour one really needs a [mcve] to be able to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You normally want to avoid using pyplot in a GUI application. So if I understand correctly the `UsersPlatformPie` subclasses `MyMplCanvas`, which means that you have the axes to plot on available as `self.axes`.

Therefore do

```
self.axes.pie(sizes, colors = colors, labels = labels, autopct = '%1.1f%%', shadow = True)
self.axes.set_title('Users Per Platform')
self.axes.set_aspect('1')
self.axes.figure.canvas.draw()
```

Comment: I tried this method as it is also used in the linked documentation but I get a "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'draw'" error.

Comment: Oh ha. Now we have an error. So you want me (or anyone else) to solve it without having access to a [mcve], it that what you're saying?

Comment: I've submitted an edit for your answer which produces the desired result, only by deleting the last line. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If the last line doesn't work something else is not correct in your application.

Comment: If I encounter such a problem I'll update this query with an MCV example.